# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy' opencv error coming when running code

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am having an issue with this Python code:
[Code And Other Things](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11dJqibdXGIZgSUEOgyA0l22yx16Cn2qJ?usp=sharing)

The Error Is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thaku\Desktop\projects\pythoncode-tutorials-master\machine-learning\face-age-prediction\predict_age.py", line 156, in <module>
    predict_age(image_path)
  File "C:\Users\thaku\Desktop\projects\pythoncode-tutorials-master\machine-learning\face-age-prediction\predict_age.py", line 113, in predict_age
    frame = img.copy()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

I Was trying opencv as learning python. the project was to predict age but as this error came my days are wasted so please help me..
To Run The Code: python .\predict_age.py  /tmp
or some new errors come

Comment: You should paste your code here in the question instead of linking to it.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask]. We can only tell you what is wrong with code that you show *in the question itself*.

Answer (score 2):

```
def predict_age(input_path: str):
"""Predict the age of the faces showing in the image"""
# Read Input Image
img = cv2.imread(input_path)
# Take a copy of the initial image and resize it
frame = img.copy()
```

Seems your error happens here because img is None, so it has no method copy() to call.

You said you are running the code like this:

```
 .\predict_age.py /tmp
```

I can see that the code initialises img with the input_path which is passed as sys.argv[1]. well, /tmp is not really an image, could you try passing an image like .\predict_age.py /tmp/my_image.png

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the `img` variable from `cv2.imread(input_path)` is `None`. I.e., something went wrong with reading the image from `input_path`.

In your main code, you write

```
import sys
image_path = sys.argv[1]
predict_age(image_path)
```

So the image path is given by the first argument to the program. Are you running the code as `python predict_age.py 3-people.jpg`?

Comment: Hey Lucas, seems like we've seen the same thing and replied at the same time, haha

Comment: yes it doesn't work